# Check whether string match or not

Tags: ruby

I have a string and an array with some strings.
as below

```
hostname = TETDC3DBE01

Array  = ['WEB','APP','STR','DBE']
```

I want to find whether that hostname match with any of the array element or not?

When I'm trying with below code getting output

```
no
no
no
no
```

Here is loop repeating each and every element on array. I want check that hostname with single check on array the produce the output either yes or no only.

```
Array.each do |x|
  if hostname.match(x)
    puts "yes"
  else
    puts "no"
  end
end
```

Comment: First you shouldn't redefine Array. `'TETDC3DBE01'.match('WEB') # nil
'TETDC3DBE01'.match('APP') # nil
'TETDC3DBE01'.match('STR') # nil` all nil, so they don't match, what are you really trying to do?

Comment: Now I want output only "yes"

Comment: Isn't `hostname.match(x)` working?

Comment: Try `['WEB','APP','STR','DBE'].map { |s| hostname.match?(/#{s}/) ? 'yes' : 'no' } #=> ["no", "no", "no", "yes"]`. You want `hostname = 'TETDC3DBE01'` (i.e., with single or double quotes). Better edit that now, 
 before it attracts downvotes..

Comment: I am getting out as "no
no
no
yes"  I want only either yes or no

Comment: Note: Ruby is a case-sensitive language and capital letters have specific meaning in terms of syntax. Variables and method names should be lower-case letters. Capitals indicate constants of the form  `ClassName` or `CONSTANT_NAME`. `Array` is actually an existing constant, you can't use that name.

Comment: @mahesha "I want either yes or no" - take a look at [Enumerable#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

Answer (score 2):

Given this fixed Ruby code:

```
hostname = 'TETDC3DBE01'

array  = ['WEB','APP','STR','DBE']
```

Where if you want to find all elements in `array` that match as a substring of `hostname` your code should work. The more minimal matching system is probably:

```
array.select { |x| hostname.match(x) }
# => ["DBE"]
```

Using a tool like `puts` to produce output isn't always very useful because that "yes" or "no" text can't be acted upon by more code. Try and think of Ruby programs as a chain of transformations, where this selects all matches, and later you can print them, like this:

```
puts array.select { |x| hostname.match(x) }.join(',')
# => DBE
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Array#any?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) method.

It passes each element of the collection to the given block. The method returns true if the block ever returns a value other than false or nil. If the block is not given, Ruby adds an implicit block of `{ |obj| obj }` that will cause `any?` to return true if at least one of the collection members is not false or nil.

If instead a pattern is supplied, the method returns whether `pattern === element` for any collection member.

In your case:

```
hostname = 'TETDC3DBE01'
['WEB','APP','STR','DBE'].any? do |x|
  hostname.match(x)
end
```

or even if you actually mean *equal* by *match*:

```
hostname = 'TETDC3DBE01'
['WEB','APP','STR','DBE'].any?(hostname)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regexp in this case. A simple `String#include?` is probably faster. Furthermore [`any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) will return `true` if any of the elements in the array leads is matching.

```
hostname = 'TETDC3DBE01'
array  = ['WEB','APP','STR','DBE']

array.any? { |x| hostname.include?(x) }
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets take your code to fix it.

```
hostname = "TETDC3DBE01"

arr  = ['WEB','APP','STR','DBE']

 arr.each do |x|
  if hostname.match?(x)
   puts "yes"
  else
   puts "no"
  end
end
```

`match` gives array of result and
`match?` gives you true or false value

Answer (score 0):

Regular expression made real easy:

```
hostname = "TETDC3DBE01"
array  = ['WEB','APP','STR','DBE']

re = Regexp.union(array)
hostname.match?(re)  # => true
```